# Caesar Cipher in Python: remove spaces in a list

Tags: python, list, input, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a Caesar Cypher project. I take the user's input, turn it into a list, take out spaces, and then encrypt the letters.

My question is: How do I re-add these spaces into the final encrypted message?

Here's what I have achieved so far (pretend word = message)

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

en_de = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt your message? ")
word = input("Enter a word: ")
shift = input("Enter a number: ")

word = list(word)

indexes = []

def encrypt():
  for letters in word:
    if letters in alphabet:
      index = (alphabet.index(letters))
      int(index)
      indexes.append(index)
  print(indexes)
  n = 0
  n = n + int(shift)
  for i in range(len(indexes)):
   indexes[i] = indexes[i] + n
  print(indexes)
  ceaser_cipher = ''
  for i in indexes:
    if i > len(alphabet)-1:
      i %= len(alphabet)
    ceaser_cipher = ceaser_cipher + (alphabet[i])
  for 
  print(ceaser_cipher)

def decrypt():
  for letters in word:
    index = (alphabet.index(letters))
    int(index)
    indexes.append(index)
  print(indexes)
  n = 0
  n = n + int(shift)
  for i in range(len(indexes)):
   indexes[i] = indexes[i] - n
  print(indexes)
  ceaser_cipher = ''
  for i in indexes:
    if i > len(alphabet)-1:
      i %= len(alphabet)
    ceaser_cipher = ceaser_cipher + (alphabet[i])
  print(ceaser_cipher)  

if en_de == "encrypt":
  encrypt()
elif en_de == "decrypt":
  decrypt()
```

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why not just leave spaces alone? Encrypt the letters, skip spaces and other characters for which you don't have a mapping.

Comment: I apologise for not clarifying before. I have edited it to show what I have typed out so far.

Answer (score 3):

The structure I would go for, is like this:

```
input_string = input("Enter message or cipher: ")
input_list = input_string.split(" ")
# input_list will be a list of each word in input_string
# encrypt each word in input_list and append each encrypted word 
# to a new list, let's say that list is called output_list
output = " ".join(output_list)
# output will be a string of each item in the list separated by spaces
```

The final program could look something like this:

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
message = input("message or cipher: ").lower().split(" ")
shift = int(input("shift: "))
shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
cipher_list = []
for word in message:
    cipher_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        cipher_word += shifted_alphabet[alphabet.index(letter)]
    cipher_list.append(cipher_word)
print(" ".join(cipher_list))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering as well as helping improve structure. I'll definitely implement some of these tips into the program.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path in your learning, and @Toby's answer is a good contribution for you.

I'd like to just **tease** you here and let you know that the whole ["Caesar Cipher"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) can be fully implemented in a one-liner, once you get familiar with many other Python features and syntax.

Check this:

```
''.join(chr(a + (i - a + shift) % 26) if (a := 65) <= (i := ord(c)) <= 90 or (a := 97) <= i <= 122 else c for c in word)
```

Examples:

```
cipher = lambda w, s: ''.join(chr(a + (i - a + s) % 26) if (a := 65) <= (i := ord(c)) <= 90 or (a := 97) <= i <= 122 else c for c in w)

word = 'Hello, beautiful World!'
print(cipher(word, 4)) # positive shift
# Lipps, fieyxmjyp Asvph!

word = 'Lipps, fieyxmjyp Asvph!'
print(cipher(word, -4)) # -4 shift means decipher a +4 shift
# Hello, beautiful World!
```

---

**Explanation**:

- [`''.join(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes a sequence of strings `seq` and concatenate them together into one string;
- [`ord(c)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) gives index of the character `c` in the Unicode table. For example, `ord('a')` returns the integer `97` and `ord('A')` returns the integer `65`;
- [`chr(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) is the inverse of `ord`: It gives the character at index `i` in the Unicode table. For example, `chr(122)` returns the string `'z'` and `chr(90)` returns the string `'Z'`;
- `... for c in word` is a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/). Is a nice compact and efficient idiom for creating a sequence from another sequence. In this case, I am taking every character `c` in the string `word`, performing an operation, and creating a new sequence with each resulting element.
- `... if ... else ...` is the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). It is a shortcut to embed a condition in an expression. Here, if the character index is not between 65 and 90 (uppercase letters) or between 97 and 122 (lowercase letters), I am returning the same character `c` untouched. That makes any non-letter not get transformed by the cipher (like space, comma, or exclamation mark);
- `x <= y <= z` is a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#not-in), it is a nice idiom available in python that resembles the Math conditional expression.
- `(a := 65)` and `(i := ord(c))` make use of the [walrus operator :=](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), aka "assignment expression". With this, you can assign a variable at the same time you use it in an expression, and this variable will be available for use in the enclosed context after the declaration. For example, `i` is assigned in the left side of the `or` operator, and is used in the right side. Also, `a` is assigned in the "test" part of the conditional and used in the "expression" part.
- `chr(a + (i - a + shift) % 26)` is performing a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) with the python's [operator %](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), where `26` is the count of letters from A to Z. That means, if your `shift` makes your letter overflow the alphabet, it circles back to the beginning/end. For example, `'B'` with a shift of `-4` gives `'X'`, and `'x'` with a shift of `+30` gives `'b'` (because `30 = 26 + 4`);

---

It is a rather contrived implementation, but hopefully you got to know some new stuff today on python!

Comment: Wow, I have a lot to learn! Thank you for explaining each part of your answer, and how everything works. It's annoying when I receive an answer, but not a good explanation on how everything works, or why it makes sense to use that answer. Thanks again!